# How to stop jquery animate at onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in jquery, I don't know much about it, but I need it because I'm building a template...Here is situation, I have a div which I want to slide in to page ( from outside, top) when I click on link, and when I click anywhere else on the page to slide out... This is what I have:

```
var tmpl_name = '<?php echo $this->template ?>';
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('#link').click(function() {
    var topy = jQuery('#div');
      topy.delay(0).animate({
      top: parseInt(topy.css('top')) == 0 ? -topy.outerWidth() : 10
    },500, 'easeInOutCirc', function() {jQuery(this);});
  });

});
```

...and it works well,when I click on link div slide in to page, but I don't know how to achieve when I click anywhere else on page to slide out the div, I have tried to add:

```
jQuery('body').click(function() {
    var topy = jQuery('#div');
      topy.delay(0).animate({
      top: parseInt(topy.css('top')) == 0 ? -topy.outerWidth() : -500
    },1000, 'easeInOutCirc', function() {jQuery(this);});
  });
```

...but problem is when I click on link to slide in div, div goes in and out of page ( probably because link is also in body and this second part of code affects it too.

Thanks for your time...Best regards

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('#link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var topy = jQuery('#div');
      topy.delay(0).animate({
      top: parseInt(topy.css('top')) == 0 ? -topy.outerWidth() : 10
    },500, 'easeInOutCirc', function() {jQuery(this);});
  });

});
```

To kill the event propagation to the document object

Answer (score 0):

The `.stop()` function can be chained at the beginning of your call as well at the end to stop any animations.

i.e.  `$("#element").stop().bounce().stop();`